# How to access all the files before compilation?

Tags: c

There are several steps involved from the stage of writing a C program to the stage of getting it executed.
when I compile the code I only get an .exe file. But I want to get all the files which are being made before the compilation (preprocess ones), an intermediate code file
where all those macros with are replaced with  their actual values  and preprocessor are replaced with their actual header files.
in general can we get all those files  (preprocess one, compile one and linker one) separately?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica dev c++ 5.11

Answer (score 1):

To access all the intermediate files use the command (Ubuntu):
`gcc –Wall –save-temps filename.c –o filename`. This command generates all the intermediate files in current working directory.

Comment: can you explain how to use this command?

Comment: os is windows 8

Comment: Open command line in Windows. Change directory to the file directory. Then type that command.  That's it.

Comment: Learn how to use command line in Windows. I am not sure, if this command works on Windows OS. It works on Ubuntu OS.

Comment: i tried it on cmd but it did not work on it

Comment: there is no other way to get this file ,without using any command line

Comment: Did you change the directory?? Did you change the filename ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i changed the name but i didnot changed the directory

Comment: It should work on Windows using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), is a port of `gcc`

Comment: @DavidRanieri can you explain that command because i know very less about cmd

Comment: Basically instead of using your RAD to compile, you launch the compiler from a console, for short programs it can be compiled using `gcc` directly, for larger ones we use a `Makefile` containing the rules, I suggest you to check how to send parameters to the compiler from your RAD, i.e. `Options\Build\gcc` on QTCreator and add this `-save-temps` to the toolchain.